# Making Material-UI Autocomplete break long words to fit layout

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

It is the first time that I am dealing with the Material-UI autocomplete.
In my case I use it with usernames, which can only have a certain length but it might not fit into the autocomplete view, due to restricted size.

[image: autocomplete usage example]

As you can see in the sandbox and image, the words are cut off if they are too long.

So therefore I'm looking for a way to expand the dropdown's width, when it is clicked, depending on the options string length or implement a word-break for too long words.

As it can be seen in the sandbox, I tried out using different ways to make the text overflow or break words into a new line, but unsuccessful until now.

[Sandbox-Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-b1r151?file=/demo.js)

Can anyone please guide me on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed that by adding `componentProps` to the list attributes passed into Autocomplete.

This makes the dropdown with the usernames wider than the input field and guarantees width corresponding to maximum username length or fixed length as shown in my code.

```
<Autocomplete
        id="select_user_history"
        options={users}
        value={selectedUser}
        // --------
        // following block solves it
        componentsProps={{
            paper: {
                sx: {
                    width: 160
                }
            }
        }}
        // --------
        getOptionLabel={e => e.name}
        .....
        )}
    />
```

Comment: What if the text length is variable?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by text lenght? You're talking about username-like as in my use-case or longer texts?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a line break with this:

```html
<Autocomplete
  ...
  componentsProps={{ paper: { sx: { wordBreak: 'break-word' } } }}
/>
```

[Result of wordBreak: 'break-word'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvN8R.png)